# Python Flask "Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Tags: api, flask, data-science

I have a project where I need to build an API for a machine learning model And I am having issues testing my API. The machine learning model is really simple: my model tries to predict the chance of a student getting admission to a Master's program given some variables such as CGPA, GRE score, University Ranking, and other stuff.

I have tried to google this issue and it seems like it has something to do with methods being called in the "predict" function But I can not seem to pinpoint and was hoping someone here helps me. I am sure I am missing something:

Here is my code for API:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import requests
import joblib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def nothello():
    return "Welcome to machine learning model APIs!"

@app.route("/index")
def hello():
    return 'My First API' 

@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():
    json_ = request.get_json(force=True)
    query_df = pd.DataFrame(json_)
    query_df = query_df.reindex(columns=model_columns, fill_value=0)
    
    #Fixing ranges for variables.
    for name in query_df:
        if name == 'GRE Score':
            for value in query_df[name]:
                if 290>value or value>340:
                    return 'GRE Score out of range!'
        elif name == 'TOEFL Score':
            for value in query_df[name]:
                if 0>value or value>120:
                    return 'Toefl score out of range!'
        elif name == 'University Rating':
            for value in query_df[name]:
                if 1>value or value>5:
                    return 'University Rating out of range!'
        elif name == 'SOP':
            for value in query_df[name]:
                if 1>value or value>5:
                    return 'SOP out of range!'
        elif name == 'LOR':
            for value in query_df[name]:
                if 1>value or value>5:
                    return 'LOR out of range!'
        elif name == 'CGPA':
            for value in query_df[name]:
                if 0>value or value>9.0:
                    return 'CGPA out of range!'
        elif name == 'Research':
            for value in query_df[name]:
                if 0>value or value>1:
                    return 'Research out of range!'
        
                
    prediction = model.predict(query_df)
    return jsonify({'prediction': list(prediction),'scores':query_df.to_dict()})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = joblib.load("model.pkl") # Load "model.pkl"
    print ('Model loaded')
    model_columns = joblib.load("model_columns.pkl") # Load "model_columns.pkl"
    print ('Model columns loaded')
    app.run(debug=False)
```

To test this API, I created another .py file in my local directory to and tried feeding a sample observation to my API to get a prediciton. Here is the code for that request:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict'
r = requests.get(url,json={'GRE Score':[339],'TOEFL Score':[107],'University Rating':[3.7],'SOP':[3.37],\
                          'LOR':[3.48],'CGPA':[8.58],'Research':[0.56]})

#print(r.json())
```

When I run Request.py and then try opening the link: http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict, I get the bad request page. If someone can assist me in realizing my mistake, I will be grateful.

Comment: Are the column names consistent for train and prediction calls?

Comment: I have double-checked. They are. Do you think it might be an issue with Request.py? 

I was thinking there something wrong with my api.

Comment: What does the error say on the server/flask console?  You can also turn on debug mode so you get a pretty error.  Normally a bad request is 'my app is trying to access a dictionary key that isn't there' like if you submitted a form and checked for a field that wasn't in the form.  Could also `print(json_)` just after you load it to see if the data there is what you expect-- the `force=True` might be causing your expectations to be different then reality.

Comment: Why not use `requests.post` in your second file? It doesn't look like you're separating the get/post handling, so `post` appears to be handled better.

Comment: Guys I had lost my laptop and have only logged in today. I figured it out! The issue was simple: My knack of knowledge. the request. code where "#print(r.json())" is written, That is where my answer was saved all along!